# issue in returning profile_image url in update serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to add base url in uploaded `profile_image` but it's returning `null` value.
the code for update serializer is below-

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    profile = instance.profile
    username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
    if instance.username != username:
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        try:
            if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=instance.username).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError("username already exists")
        except Exception as e:
                error = {'message': ",".join(e.args) if len(e.args) > 0 else 'Unknown Error'}
                raise serializers.ValidationError(error)
    instance.profile_image = validated_data.get('profile_image', instance.profile_image)
    instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
    instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
    instance.save()
    profile.phone = profile_data.get('phone', profile.phone)
    profile.date_of_birth = profile_data.get('date_of_birth', profile.date_of_birth)
    profile.country = profile_data.get('country', profile.country)
    profile.city = profile_data.get('city', profile.city)
    profile.zip = profile_data.get('zip', profile.zip)
    profile.active = profile_data.get('active', profile.active)
    profile.save()
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user_obj.profile_image == "":
        photo_url = ""
    else:
        photo_url = BASE_URL + str(user_obj.profile_image)
    print(photo_url)
    return {
        "id": user_obj.id,
        "username": user_obj.username,
        "email": user_obj.email,
        "profile_image": photo_url, #here is the problem
        "first_name": user_obj.first_name,
        "last_name": user_obj.last_name,
        "profile":{
                "phone": profile.zip,
                "date_of_birth": profile.date_of_birth,
                "country": profile.country,
                "city": profile.city,
                "zip": profile.zip,
                "active": profile.active
        }
    }
```

can anyone tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, update method of the serializer should return updated instance (`instance` variable in this case).

And now... when photo_url is properly defined in then serializer (in Meta.fields tuple and defined as property in your serializer (! *IMPORTANT BECAUSE IT DOES NOT EXIST IN MODEL*) and your serializer `update` method will set this parameter on returned instance before return it should return good value `BASE_URL + str(user_obj.profile_image)`

**BUT**

only  after PUT/PATCH request because only in `method` it's defined.

So i suggest you to define `photo_url = serializers.ImageField(src="profile_image ", read_only=True)` field and it should do the work without any problem.

OK, that was explanation, now it's opinion - it's horribly bad - but i wrote some serializer for you to compare it (please - always post full context of the serializer - not only update method)..

update/fix my answer when it has errors - writing on air - but whole concept should be understood

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #...bla bla fields definition CharField, ImageField etc....
    photo_url = serializers.ImageField(src="profile_image", read_only=True)
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            # ....fields 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile', ...etc
            'photo_url'
        )
    
    def update(instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', {}) 
        # Always pass second argument (default value) 
        # because pop method will raise error when 'profile' 
        # key would be not in dictionary 
        instance.profile.update(**profile_data)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

voilà